# Scope of jQuery each() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, each

I'm working with the jQuery ColorPicker widget - specifically exercising the ColorPickerSetColor function (just 'setColor' internally).  Code excerpt:

```
        setColor: function(col) {
            if (typeof col == 'string') {
                col = HexToHSB(col);
            } else if (col.r != undefined && col.g != undefined && col.b != undefined) {
                col = RGBToHSB(col);
            } else if (col.h != undefined && col.s != undefined && col.b != undefined) {
                col = fixHSB(col);
            } else {
                return this;
            }
            return this.each(function(){
                if ($(this).data('colorpickerId')) {
                    var cal = $('#' + $(this).data('colorpickerId'));
                    cal.data('colorpicker').color = col;
                    cal.data('colorpicker').origColor = col;
                    fillRGBFields(col, cal.get(0));
                    fillHSBFields(col, cal.get(0));
                    fillHexFields(col, cal.get(0));
                    setHue(col, cal.get(0));
                    setSelector(col, cal.get(0));
                    setCurrentColor(col, cal.get(0));
                    setNewColor(col, cal.get(0));
                }
            });
        }
```

It seems that there is a bug in the widget.  The 'col' parameter, when inspected inside of the each() call, is undefined.  I've read the documentation and other examples, and everything I can find indicates that 'col' should still be in scope when the each() call executes the function, but it doesn't seem to be...

Help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure col is defined before the return this.each is reached?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  If we add a console.log (Firebug's logging command) right before and right after the return this.each, the first log() command outputs a valid value, while the second only outputs undefined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using a temporary variable in a known-good scope (the parent of the setColor function).  Definitely a hack, but it works.  If anyone knows how to fix this the right way, please let me know. :)

Thanks!
-Rich

Comment: If you have the time and desire, you should write up a very minimal piece of code that duplicates the issue.  In the process of doing this, you may even learn why it's happening.  If you do, please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining another variable:

```
 setColor: function(xCol) {
     var col = xCol;
     // ...
 }
```

If that works, then there's a weirdness in the closure system when it comes to parameters to functions.  That sort of behavior could be browser-specific.

Comment: Hi John!  Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, it didn't work...  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Try setting the function to a variable before the return statement, then passing that variable as the parameter to "return this.each(f);"  If that doesn't help, you'll need to post more of the code.